# How to correctly apply style to Open Office XML Bookmark text

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have prepared a MS Word document template ,and inserted bookmarks where I would like to insert text.  Currently, I am able to insert text, but all native styling is gone (ie: font size/style) I was expecting the styles to be inherited.

I've been referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42515339/edit-word-bookmark-changes-the-font) for inspiration, but I receive malformed XML:

```
<w:rFonts w:ascii="Playfair Display" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" />
```

Here is a snippet of the bookmark start/end I am working with:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<w:p xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" w:rsidR="00300E4C" w:rsidRDefault="00582F11">
   <w:pPr>
      <w:spacing w:before="265" />
      <w:ind w:left="2822" w:right="1122" />
      <w:jc w:val="center" />
      <w:rPr>
         <w:rFonts w:ascii="Playfair Display" />
         <w:i />
         <w:sz w:val="88" />
      </w:rPr>
   </w:pPr>
   <w:bookmarkStart w:name="F_4000" w:id="0" />
   <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0" />
   <w:r>
      <w:rPr>
         <w:rFonts w:ascii="Playfair Display" />
         <w:i />
         <w:color w:val="113628" />
         <w:sz w:val="88" />
      </w:rPr>
      <w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t>
   </w:r>
   <w:bookmarkStart w:name="F_4002" w:id="1" />
   <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="1" />
</w:p>
```

When using the following code:

```c#
IEnumerable<OpenXmlElement> elementsAfter = bookmark.ElementsAfter();
IEnumerable<OpenXmlElement> insideBookmark = elementsAfter.TakeWhile(element => !(element is BookmarkEnd));
foreach (OpenXmlElement element in insideBookmark)
{
    element.RemoveAllChildren();
}

OpenXmlElement previousSibling = bookmark.PreviousSibling();
while (previousSibling is BookmarkStart || previousSibling is BookmarkEnd)
{
    previousSibling = previousSibling.PreviousSibling();
}

//Get previous font.
var runProperties = previousSibling.GetFirstChild<ParagraphMarkRunProperties>().GetFirstChild<RunFonts>();
//var runProperties = previousSibling.GetFirstChild<RunProperties>(); - if its simple element.

// Clone.
var newProperty = (RunFonts)runProperties.Clone();

// Create container with properties
// This is where I run into malformed XML for newProperty
var container = new Run(text)
{
    RunProperties = new RunProperties() { RunFonts = newProperty }
};
```

EDIT:  After inserting some text into the bookmark locations here is the XML (the paragraph XML that contains the XML)

```xml
<w:p w:rsidR="00300E4C" w:rsidRDefault="00582F11" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
  <w:pPr>
    <w:spacing w:before="265" />
    <w:ind w:left="2822" w:right="1122" />
    <w:jc w:val="center" />
    <w:rPr>
      <w:rFonts w:ascii="Playfair Display" />
      <w:i />
      <w:sz w:val="88" />
    </w:rPr>
  </w:pPr>
  <w:r>
    <w:t>First</w:t>
  </w:r>
  <w:bookmarkStart w:name="F_4000" w:id="0" />
  <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0" />
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:rFonts w:ascii="Playfair Display" />
      <w:i />
      <w:color w:val="113628" />
      <w:sz w:val="88" />
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t>
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:t>Last</w:t>
  </w:r>
  <w:bookmarkStart w:name="F_4002" w:id="1" />
  <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="1" />
</w:p>
```

I'm just trying to grab the native (already active) style, but I think the bookmark is breaking it up somehow.  Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: No way of telling what effect this code is having on the Word Open XML... It would help to see the XML it produces (same snippet, after the code has run). What I can say, just looking at the XML and assuming bookmark F_4001 is meant: The content needs to go into the `<w:t>` tag and no where else. You shouldn't be needing to create new runs, etc. Note that this applies *only to this instance*. Bookmarks are "slippery things" inside of Word Open XML. Content Controls are much more predictable and preferred as "data targets" when working with Word Open XML.

Comment: @CindyMeister I've ran the program (see edit) and insert text into bookmarks F_4001 and F_4002 - Is the newly added run (where I'm placing the text) the issue then? It seems I am placing it in a w:t element.

Comment: I assume the "First" and "Last" text is what the code inserts? Your runs are missing the `<w:rPr>` information in the original, which is where the non-paragraph formatting is stored (the color). Either you need to include that in what you're creating *or* you need to write the new text to the existing `<w:t>` element, so that it picks up the formatting of that run. Or write the color to the `w:pPr` tag so that it's applied to the entire paragraph, not just the run. You might find it helpful to manually create a sample result then use the compare feature in the Open XML SDK Productiviy Tool.

Comment: @CindyMeister Is there a straight forward way to simply write to the existing `<w:t>` tag?  The location/node I am getting is the location of the bookmark within the XML.  If there is more information that might be helpful I can provide that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I eventually figured out is below.  The biggest help was using the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool to figure out what sort of structure I need to be inserting into.  The two spots I needed to input text into were situated in a strange manner, so it was easier to do them in one go, and for the rest of the elements I just InsertAfterSelf()

```
if (bookMarkEnd.Key == "F_4000" || bookMarkEnd.Key == "F_4002")
{
     OpenXmlElement previousSibling = bookMarkEnd.Value.Parent.PreviousSibling();

     while (previousSibling is BookmarkStart || previousSibling is BookmarkEnd)
     {
         previousSibling = previousSibling.PreviousSibling();
     }

     OpenXmlElement next = bookMarkEnd.Value.NextSibling<Run>();

     if (next != null)
     {
         next.GetFirstChild<Text>().Text = bookMarkEnd.Key + " " + "F_4002";
     }
}
```

Comment: thanks for mentioning "Open XML SDK Productivity Tool". This tool indeed is the biggest help.